# Can't get my external/USB wifi antenna (Alfa AWUS036ACH) to work with Ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: networking, wireless, realtek

I'm trying to use an external wifi antenna. I can plug it but it doesn't seem to start (no flashing light on the antenna). The antenna works fine on my wife's macbook.

My system is:

```
$ lsb_release -sd
Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
$ uname -a
Linux poulpito 5.4.0-52-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 15 10:57:00 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

There is no dual-boot, just this OS on this computer.

Hardware is connected:

```
$ lsusb | grep -i wlan
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0bda:8812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8812AU 802.11a/b/g/n/ac 2T2R DB WLAN Adapter
```

I think I'm OK with the driver:

```
$ apt list rtl8812au-dkms
rtl8812au-dkms/focal,focal,now 4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg-0ubuntu12 all  [installé]
$ dkms status | grep 8812
rtl8812au, 4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg, 5.4.0-52-generic, x86_64: installed
$ lsmod | grep 8812
8812au               1290240  0
cfg80211              704512  2 8812au,8821ce
```

Each time I plug the antenna's USB cable, I get this in `dmesg` (I'm not really able to interpret it but I can read "USB device found"):

```
[ 1737.888170] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=8812, bcdDevice= 0.00
[ 1737.895453] Modules linked in: rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep binfmt_misc snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm edac_mce_amd snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event kvm_amd ccp snd_rawmidi kvm crct10dif_pclmul uvcvideo snd_seq ghash_clmulni_intel videobuf2_vmalloc btusb videobuf2_memops amdgpu btrtl videobuf2_v4l2 btbcm videobuf2_common aesni_intel btintel snd_seq_device crypto_simd cryptd glue_helper asus_nb_wmi serio_raw bluetooth videodev asus_wmi hid_multitouch nls_iso8859_1 8812au(OE) sparse_keymap 8821ce(OE) wmi_bmof k10temp snd_timer joydev mc input_leds amd_iommu_v2 gpu_sched ecdh_generic ttm ecc snd cfg80211 drm_kms_helper i2c_algo_bit fb_sys_fops syscopyarea sysfillrect soundcore sysimgblt mac_hid asus_wireless sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm ip_tables x_tables autofs4 usbhid hid_generic crc32_pclmul ahci nvme i2c_piix4 libahci r8169 realtek
[ 1737.895589]  ? _rtw_malloc+0x2d/0x2f [8812au]
[ 1737.895622]  ? _rtw_memcpy+0x10/0x12 [8812au]
[ 1737.895657]  ? rtw_5g_rates_init+0x1a/0x1c [8812au]
[ 1737.895690]  ? rtw_spt_band_alloc+0xb0/0xb2 [8812au]
[ 1737.895723]  rtw_wdev_alloc+0xf6/0x29c [8812au]
[ 1737.895755]  rtw_usb_if1_init+0xf0/0x20c [8812au]
[ 1737.895786]  rtw_drv_init+0x246/0x2d3 [8812au]
```

At this point, I believe I'm supposed to see the light flashing on the antenna and a WLAN interface should appear but it's not:

```
$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp4s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"giluxphone"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.432 GHz  Access Point: 8A:36:5F:BF:0A:B4   
      Bit Rate:72.2 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0  
      Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=100/100  Signal level=-32 dBm  Noise level=0 dBm
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

$ nmcli device status
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION   
wlp3s0  wifi      connecté      giluxphone 1 
enp4s0  ethernet  indisponible  --           
lo      loopback  non-géré      --           

$ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp4s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 04:d4:c4:e5:9c:a1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c0:e4:34:1b:80:0b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

(Note that `wlp3s0` is my internal wireless card, not the external USB antenna that I'm trying to use).

So what should I do now? Is there something in `dmesg` output suggesting that something doesn't work?

To me, it seems like everything is OK but I must have missed something...

Comment: I would remove the rtl8812au-dkms and find a github source that has been recently updated like https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Jeremy31 in the comments, I removed the driver installed via apt:

```
sudo apt purge rtl8812au-dkms
```

and installed another driver. There are plenty of options on Github, just search for "8812au". I chose the one from Aircrak-NG because their repo is fairly up-to-date and seems to be backed by a stronger community.

Clone the repo anywhere (source will be copied to /usr/src during DKMS install anyway) and then start the DKMS install:

```
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au/
sudo make dkms_install
sudo modprobe 88XXau
```

And now, when I plug the antenna, I can see its blue led flashing and there is an interface representing it:

```
$ ip link 
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp4s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 04:d4:c4:e5:9c:a1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c0:e4:34:1b:80:0b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: wlx00c0caa8537a: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 2312 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:c0:ca:a8:53:7a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I still have to figure out how to give precedence to this antenna over the internal wireless card but this is another question.

Answer (score 0):

This just short Tutorial for NEWBIE (like me!) for installing driver USB Wifi driver for Linux Debian and it’s derivatives (Debian, Ubuntu, Linux Mint, Pop! OS, Elementary OS, etc.)

When you're switch to new OS distro or updating OS or accidently delete some part of software sometimes your Wifi driver are no support / no working and got blank your mind ... Yup thats right !

**First STEP to do :**

1. You only need YOUR SMARTPHONES and make sure also they have “Internet Mobile Data”.
2. Then you need to opened “Developer Options” on your smartphone to do that first before.
3. Open your phone “Settings” and find it “About Phone” and selected “Version Number” and then now repeated click up to (7x) seven times.
4. Inside “Developer Options” find it or scrolling to the “Network” and selected “Select USB Configuration” and then select again to the “USB Ethernet (RNDIS)”.
5. After this all you need is USB cable connected to your PC or Laptop and it’s done, now you ready online!

**Second STEP to do :**

1. Installing GDebi (I’m using Geary on Pop! OS that are the same software). You can find GDebi in Ubuntu Software Center,  just search for it and install it from there.
2. Then installing the latest “realtek-rtl88xxau-dkms” deb package from Kali’s repository (mostly update - link below!).
3. After this just type in your linux terminal “sudo reboot” to rebooting your PC or Laptop.
4. It’s done , just try to check it out !

I’m trying many times using this method when i switching to new OS distros or update Linux Kernel. This really saving my times and work to do! Thanks for your time to read this !

**Source :**

- https://http.kali.org/kali/pool/contrib/r/realtek-rtl88xxau-dkms/
- https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options
- https://itsfoss.com/gdebi-default-ubuntu-software-center/